# Export 3d Track from After Effects 2017 to Blender 2.8

Tags: javascript, python, blender, after-effects

I have a footage 3d tracked in After Effects 2017 , now I want to export the tracked nulls and solids to Blender and add some effects.

Is there any way to export the data , any Script(free) ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out https://aescripts.com/fbx-to-ae/.

It can export to fbx from AE and Blender can then import the fbx.
But you'll have to convert the fbx file from ASCII to binary using the software available here: https://www.autodesk.com/developer-network/platform-technologies/fbx-converter-archives, which may not work in OSX Catalina if you're on that platform (it may, though, I haven't tried. It works in Mojave, but this may be a moot point if you're on Windows)

[edit - 12/2021] Another option I just discovered and tested out is https://blendermarket.com/products/ae2blend/ and it's very inexpensive - only 10 USD.
It works very nicely. The Blender add-on recognizes ae keyframe data. Just make sure you read the manual and watch a tutorial - you may have to enter a camera property bit by hand. Other than that (which is super easy) it works well.

Comment: I realize it's not free, but it's pretty cheap, and seems to be the only way to do what you want. Glad it seems to work for you!